# Is there another way to solve this equation?

Tags: problem-solving

My problem is Solve the equation
$$2 \left(\sqrt{x^3-7 x^2+17x-14}+\sqrt{x^4-7 x^3+23x^2-37 x+28}\right)=4x^2-17 x+25.$$
And my solve.

We have
$$\sqrt{x^3-7 x^2+17x-14}= \sqrt{(x-2) \left(x^2-5 x+7\right)}\leqslant \dfrac{(x-2) + (x^2-5 x+7)}{2}= \dfrac{x^2 - 4x + 5}{2}.$$
Another way
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^4-7 x^3+23x^2-37 x+28} &= \sqrt{\left(x^2-4 x+7\right)\left(x^2-3 x+4\right)}\\
&\leqslant \dfrac{(x^2-4 x+7)+(x^2-3 x+4)}{2} \\
&= \dfrac{2x^2-7x+11}{2}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, 
$$\text{LHS} \leqslant (x^2 - 4x + 5) + (2x^2-7x+11) = 3x^2 -11x + 16.$$
From the given equation, we have
$$4x^2-17 x+25 \leqslant 3x^2 -11x + 16 \Leftrightarrow x^2 -6x + 9 \leqslant 0 \leqslant (x-3)^2 \leqslant 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 3. $$
 We see that, $x = 3$ satisfies the given equation.

Thus, the  the given equation has only solution is $x = 3.$

Is there another way to solve this equation?

Answer (score 3):

There is a very laborious way of doing it using successive squarings (which will create extra roots.

Starting with $$2(\sqrt A+\sqrt B)=C$$ a first squaring leads to $$4(A+B)-C^2=8\sqrt{AB}$$ and a second squaring leads to $$\Big(4(A+B)-C^2\Big)^2=64AB$$ Using $$A=x^3-7 x^2+17 x-14\qquad B=x^4-7 x^3+23 x^2-37 x+28\qquad C=4 x^2-17 x+25$$ this leads to $$144 x^8-2752 x^7+23640 x^6-119376 x^5+387945 x^4-831620 x^3+1149958 x^2-939876
   x+348849=0$$ By inspection, this equation shows a double root $x=3$. Then, what is left is $$144 x^6-1888 x^5+11016 x^4-36288 x^3+71073 x^2-78590 x+38761=0$$ 
As Laplacian Fourier commented, this *"last equation has no real roots by Descartes rule of signs".*

Comment: I like the part where you say 'By inspection'.  +1 for that.

Comment: You can see thAt the last equation has no real roots by decartes rule of signs

Comment: @Shailesh. Is it humor ? I always look at polynomials using $x=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3, \pm 4$ to see what happens. Cheers.

Comment: @LaplacianFourier. Thanks for pointing this key point. I shall edit quoting you.

Comment: I think, this is not a solution.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  it's just that the polynomial was a little bit unweildy and not many will be do it as easily as you did ! Cheers!